# how to use GridLayout in TabeedPanel using kivy in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tabs, kivy, textinput

I am trying to make a GUI in python using kivy and TabeedPanel . some problems are coming for putting on exact location of label, TextInput , button. I'm unable to put multiple label, TextInput altogether. That's why I commented in the code. I tried GridLayout also, but Unable to arrange exactly.
Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel, TabbedPanelItem
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
import json

Builder.load_string("""

<Test>:
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'page1'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'label'
            TextInput:
                text: 'TextInput'
            CheckBox: 
                text: 'CheckBox'
            Button:
                text: 'save'

    #BoxLayout:
     #   orientation: 'vertical'
      #  BoxLayout:
       #     orientation: 'horizontal'
        #    Label:
         #       text: 'label'



    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'page2'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'number1'
        #TextInput:
        #   text: 'TextInput'
            Label:
                text: 'number2'
       # TextInput:
       #    text: 'TextInput'
            Button:
                text: 'button'

""")

class Test(TabbedPanel):
    pass

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        test = Test()
        return test


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

[image: kivy gui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using `GridLayout` that I made a reference to in your other question. FYI, there are many ways you could go about this. I personally like using gridlayout with forms because it's easy to put then ScrollViews if need be.

Read up on the kv language [here](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html) to help keep things DRY and other things. If a widget is defined in kv, then you don't need to import them at the top of your file.

Example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<MyLabel@Label>:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (400, 100)

<MyTextInput@TextInput>:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (600, 100)

<MyButton@Button>:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (400, 100)

<MyCheckBox@AnchorLayout>:
    # I'm nesting the checkbox here b/c it is hard to see if the background is not lightened.
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (100, 100)
    anchor_x: "center"
    anchor_y: "center"
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: [0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    CheckBox:

<Test>:
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'page1'
        GridLayout:
            rows: 3
            cols: 4
            padding: [10, 100]
            spacing: [10, 50]
            MyLabel:
                text: "Label 1"
            MyTextInput:
            MyCheckBox:
            MyButton:
                text: "Button 1"
            MyLabel:
                text: "Label 3"
            MyTextInput:
            MyCheckBox:
            MyButton:
                text: "Button 2"
            MyLabel:
                text: "Label 3"
            MyTextInput:
            MyCheckBox:
            MyButton:
                text: "Button 3"


    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'page2'
        GridLayout:
            rows: 3
            cols: 2
            padding: [10, 100]
            spacing: [10, 50]
            MyLabel:
                text: "Label 1"
            MyTextInput:

            MyLabel:
                text: "Label 2"
            MyTextInput:

            # blank spacer widget
            Widget:
                size_hint: (None, None)
                size: (400, 100)
            MyButton:
                text: "Button"
""")


class Test(TabbedPanel):
    pass


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: How to fill up the label and TextInput dynamically? Like those values are  stored in a variable as a map (key, value pair) and in json format like this                                                                                                  var = '{"a" : " Goc" , "b" : "Coc", "c" : "Dow" } ')  At runtime, using any loop, the label and TextInput should fill automatically . N.B: here the 'key' data should show at  label and 'value' is at TextInput. i.e: a: Goc , b: Coc, c: Dow  . SO a,b,c are label and Goc, Coc, Dow are TextInput.

Comment: The above thing is only for "page1"

Answer (score 2):

Following your example, you can use BoxLayouts but you need to nest them correctly:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""

<Test>:
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'page1'

        BoxLayout:
            padding: 50, 50, 50, 50
            orientation: 'horizontal'

            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 50
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_x: 1
                Label:
                    text: 'label'
                Label:
                    text: 'label'
                Label:
                    text: 'label'

            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 50
                orientation: 'vertical'
                TextInput:
                    text: 'TextInput'
                TextInput:
                    text: 'TextInput'
                TextInput:
                    text: 'TextInput'

            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 50
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_x: 0.40
                CheckBox: 
                    text: 'CheckBox'
                CheckBox: 
                    text: 'CheckBox'
                CheckBox: 
                    text: 'CheckBox'

            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 50
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_x: 0.60
                Button:
                    text: 'save'
                Button:
                    text: 'save'
                Button:
                    text: 'save'


    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'page2'

        BoxLayout:
            padding: 50, 50, 50, 50
            orientation: 'horizontal'

            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 50
                orientation: 'vertical'
                Label:
                    text: 'label'
                Label:
                    text: 'label'
                Label:

            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 50
                orientation: 'vertical'
                TextInput:
                    text: 'TextInput'
                TextInput:
                    text: 'TextInput'
                Button:
                    spacing: 100
                    text: 'button'

""")

class Test(TabbedPanel):
    pass

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        test = Test()
        return test


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Output:

[image]